# Doubling of inserted character in Vim substitution

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

In Vim the command

```
:echo substitute('-bb', '\zeb', 'a', 'g')
```

prints the following output:

```
-aabab
```

Why are two letters inserted before the first b?

Comment: I don't know. My guess bug. If you create a file with contents `-bb` and run `:%s/\zeb/a/g` you get the expected output of `-abab`

Comment: @FDinoff: Yes, and if you use `b-b` instead of `-bb`, two letters are inserted before the second b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, and a patch [has been submitted](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/yYNGS1R4Pt4/Vxf5n2OZijYJ); thanks Christian!

Edit: It's been accepted as Patch 7.4.045.